# PHP Regex: How to get first number within an address string?

Tags: php, regex

I need to extract the **first** occurance of a number that is found in an address.   The addresses will always start something like (I've marked in bold what I want to match)...

- Flat **12**, Apartment 2...
- **12**, Apartment Name

To make it a bit more complex it's possible that some may have letters on one side of the number, for example...

- Flat **12**a, Apartment 2...
- **12**th Room, Building 3...

My solution so far sort of works but not properly.  I have a regex of

```
\b([0-9]+)\b
```

That gets any number surrounded by a space on either side but it firstly it is getting all occurrences not the first, which is vital to my requirements.  Secondly it doesn't handle a number with a letter on one side of it, so 12a is ignored for example.

Sample Code...

```
$subject="A 2nd test, Apartment 3, Building 1232, Random Street, RH12 4SZ";
echo "Text to find number in: $subject<BR>";
if (preg_match('\b([0-9]+)\b', $subject, $matches)) {
    echo "match, found number: ".implode(",",$matches);
}else{
    echo "no match";
}
```

Can anyone improve on what I have ?

Comment: why not just `\d+` ? when you want to get digit irrespective of what comes before or after it

Comment: Thanks @CodeManiac that is a help but it doesn't work with say "Flat 12a"...

Comment: Are letters the only thing that can come next to the integer? If so `\b\d+[a-z]*\b` should do it

Comment: @AdamJones Please share exactly what you want your pattern to match on each of your examples, it's a bit unclear. `\d+` will give you the first number, so `12` for `Flat 12a`.

Comment: To get the first occurrence you could either not use the global flag (get all matches) or use an anchor, perhaps like  `^[^\d\r\n]*(\d+)[^\d\s]* (?:Apartment|Room)` See https://regex101.com/r/vlh4Hc/1

Comment: @AdamJones just don't use global flag, it will give you just first occurrence

Comment: @CodeManiac There isn't a global flag in PHP.

Comment: @CodeManiac probably means use `preg_match` as opposed to `preg_match_all`.

Comment: @user3783243 this is good but it is working for all matches not the first.

Comment: @Thefourthbird , the 'apartment/'room' etc was just examples, it could be anything in the text string so I can't rely on specific words.

Comment: Then you could omit the last part like `^[^\d\r\n]*(\d+)`  https://regex101.com/r/0ahxJx/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird it's getting words before the first number, for example it selects all of 'Flat 12a' not '12a'

Comment: @Jeto can you clarify fully?  My examples I thought were fairly clear but I will improve, I've marked in bold the part I want in the 4 samples

Comment: @AdamJones Add your PHP usage. As noted `preg_match_all` is for every regex match, `preg_match` will bring back the first. You could use `preg_match_all` and use the first indexs.

Comment: The values are in the first capturing group `^\D*(\d+[^\W\d]*)`. See https://3v4l.org/u69pX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `\d+` should do the job.

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/vLCaf**

Comment: Thanks... this is almost perfect, I don't want the letters after numbers though so ' 2nd block' catches the '2nd' when I just want the 2.

Comment: Then just `\d+` as @CodeManiac initially suggested (see my edit). @CodeManiac, if it's right feel free to post it yourself and I'll remove mine.

Comment: @Jeto No matter either you post or i post, if it solves the problem i am happy :)

Comment: I've added a code sample, Jeto your latest linked sample seems great thank you!

Comment: @AdamJones Don't use `matches` like that. `0` is the full match then all additional indexes care capture groups. So you'll have multiple references. If this works PCRE verbs would be wrong. I thought you wanted alpha characters as well but not `nd`, `st`, `rd`.